# Projected PDO Statement: is this right?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-injection

I'm really just wanting to check the syntax on this statement and make sure that it's a statement that is safe from sql injection.  Could anyone check this for me and let me know?

```
$lookupusername= $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID =":userId"');
$lookupusername->bindParam(':userId', $userid, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$row = $lookupusername->fetch();
$username = $row['username'];
$usercountry = $row['country'];
if ($username == ""){
header('Location: index.php');
}
```

There's also this statement:

```
$sql = $conn->query('SELECT description, city, status, state, country, needsusername, howmanypeopleneeded, howmanypeoplesignedup, needs.orgname, needs.ID, titleofneed, expiredate, datesubmitted, datetime FROM needs INNER JOIN follow ON follow.followname = needs.needsusername WHERE follow.username=' . $conn->quote($username) . ' AND needs.christmas="0" AND needs.status="posted" ORDER BY datesubmitted DESC');
while ($frows = $sql->fetch()) {
```

FINAL CODE:

```
$lookupusername= $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID=:userid');
$lookupusername->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
$lookupusername->execute();
$row = $lookupusername->fetch();
$username = $row['username'];
$usercountry = $row['country'];
```

I wasn't executing the prepared statement.

Comment: no your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack, use prepared statement with parametrized query...

Comment: Take a look at [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html)

Comment: could you help me then figure out with the first statement what would be protected by sql injection?

Comment: please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY)

Comment: **If you build SQL statements using variables from the outside world, you are doing it wrong.**  It is not enough to use PDO.  You must also use query parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend `conn->[execute][1]` instead of `[query][2]`.  As that will be a real prepared statement instead of one you need to escape on.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID =:userID
```

then do:

```
bindParam(':userId', $userId, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
```

In terms of malicious content, assume for a second I pass you a `userId` that looks like this:

```
<script>alert('Hi')</script>
```

Now lets also assume you display my userId to someone that is an admin or another user.  I can potentially inject malicious code that will be executed at a later time.  So you must still take care to ensure data returned to the user is properly escaped.  But for the most part, binding parameters will prevent arbitrary SQL execution.

functional code:

```
$sql= $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID =:userID');
$sql->bindParam(':userId', $userId, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
```

Comment: so just putting execute instead of query would protect it?

Comment: no, you bindParams.  With bound parameters there is no escaping needed.

Comment: @gview kind of, it only prevents SQL from being executed not malicious data from impacting the application elsewhere.

Comment: It's saying call to undefined function bindParams()

Comment: @user2362601 its bindParam no `s`

Comment: I updated my code to show what I have.  The browser says the page redirected to too many loops.  What is causing this action?

Comment: @user2362601 can you show the full code, there is something else going on.

Comment: @Woot4Moo I put the code up.  That's all the code that has anything to do with redirecting.  The whole code is a lot.

Comment: I took out the redirect and tried to echo the username but nothing appeaers.  it's not getting a username.

Comment: @user2362601 i think it should be this: $lookupusername= $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID =:userId');  .  Notice I removed the double quotes around `:userId`

Comment: still haven't figured out why it's not working...any other ideas?

Comment: @user2362601 not sure, got any debug statements you can share.

Comment: wait don't I have to execute the prepared statement somehow?  Like I do the prepare, bindParam, and isn't there an execute code that I have to do?

Comment: I figured it out but can you check to make sure it's secure before I finish up?  I edited my post to show the final code.

Comment: @user2362601 you must bind each element individually.  I don't think binding an array is appropriate here.  But beyond that it looks more correct

Comment: Again I've edited my code to reflect what I have.  Is this secure?

Comment: @user2362601 yes that is secure from SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks for the long haul @Woot4Moo you've been very helpful and I really appreciate you.